# can't click on links inside a div opened with jquery, using preventDefault

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Bit stumped by this one, I open a dropdown menu with jquery and I don't seem to be able to click on any links inside the boxes.

I think the preventDefault is affecting everything within it, but I only want it to affect the top level. I'm not great with jquery, so I can't figure out how to make it only select the first a that's inside it to prevent the default action.

I only want the prevent default on the .toggle-nav itself.

JS:

```
// navbar toggle menu
$(".toggle-nav").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).children('.toggle-content').is(":visible"))
    {
      $(this).children('.toggle-content').hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $(".toggle-content").hide(); // hide any already open
      $(this).children('.toggle-content').show();
    }
});
```

Example of the menu:

```
<div class="toggle-nav user-box hide-small">
    <a href="#"><img src="{:avatar}" alt="" width="49" height="49"> <span class="login-caret"><span class="caret-down"></span></span></a>
        <div class="toggle-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="test">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example CSS:

```
/* toggle menus */
.toggle-content {
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 49px;
    background: #222;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
    padding: 5px;
    word-wrap: normal;
    z-index: 999999;
}
.toggle-content ul {
    list-style: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #999;
}
.toggle-content li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to the help, this is what works to toggle them and to close another when you open a new one:

```
// navbar toggle menu
$(".toggle-nav > a").on('click', function(event){
  event.preventDefault();

    var $toggle = $(this).closest('.toggle-nav').children('.toggle-content');
  if ($toggle.hasClass('toggle-active'))
  {
    $($toggle).removeClass('toggle-active');
  }
  else
  {
    $(".toggle-content").removeClass('toggle-active');
    $($toggle).addClass('toggle-active');
  }
});
```

With this added to this CSS:

```
.toggle-active {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: maybe there's an element that blocking your div

Comment: Added the CSS, nothing can be blocking it that I know of.

Comment: try looking at your inspect element and point that div and see it nothing is blocking against it.

Comment: There is nothing blocking it, as using a different method of opening it worked fine. It's the prevent default affecting all links inside the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this answer, hope this will help you

```js
// navbar toggle menu
$(".toggle-nav > a").on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
 var $toggle = $(this).closest('.toggle-nav').children('.toggle-content');
    if ($toggle.hasClass('active')){
      $($toggle).removeClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
      $($toggle).addClass('active');
    }
});
```

```css
/* toggle menus */

.toggle-content {
 display: none;
 white-space: nowrap;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0;
 top: 49px;
 background: #222;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
 padding: 5px;
 word-wrap: normal;
 z-index: 999999;
}
.toggle-content ul {
 list-style: none;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #999;
}
.toggle-content li {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.active {
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="toggle-nav user-box hide-small"> <a href="#"><img src="{:avatar}" alt="" width="49" height="49">Click me <span class="login-caret"><span class="caret-down"></span></span></a>
  <div class="toggle-content">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="test">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you wanted to work your `preventDefault()` only in your first `link` to do that remove your

```
event.preventDefault();
```

add a new event for your first link. in that event just put the `preventDefault()`

So your code would be like this

```
// navbar toggle menu
$(".toggle-nav").on("click", function(event){
    if ($(this).children('.toggle-content').is(":visible"))
    {
      $(this).children('.toggle-content').hide();
    }
    else
    {
      $(".toggle-content").hide(); // hide any already open
      $(this).children('.toggle-content').show();
    }
});

// apply this events only to your first link
$(".toggle-nav:eq(0)", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Nope, no difference.

Comment: @NaughtySquid let's continue here. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129760/cant-click-on-links-inside-a-div-opened-with-jquery-using-preventdefault

Comment: @NaughtySquid perhaps an upvote too would make me happy :)

Comment: @NaughtySquid why you unanswered my answer :(

Comment: I accepted the one I went with that I tested working that's all. Not that I don't appreciate the help :)

Answer (score -1):

Looks like it could be the "blocked div" problem. Is sometimes solved by adding `position: relative` to the element or container, which in this case would likely be `.toggle-content` or possibly more targeted (`.toggle-content ul li a` etc.). Others advise setting a high z-index as well, though I haven't found that to be necessary where the problem has surfaced for me.

Comment: The "a" right inside the "toggle-nav" is what opens the hidden content, so ".toggle-content ul li a" would do nothing. That's the wrong selector.

Comment: Was providing an example of "more precisely targeted," since I didn't know what your CSS (or anything else) was from your question before you added it. If a blocked element is the problem, it's a CSS problem, not a jQuery selector problem. I also wonder whether it would make a difference to the user if the click event was attached to the first anchor (via a unique class) rather than to the div. Jishnu VS seems to be attempting a similar alternative in the example above, (Also not sure why the whole thing isn't just handled with a simple toggle(), but that's not what you asked about.)

Comment: What do you mean by handled by a simple toggle? If there's an easier way for me to do this by all means show me an example would love to see it :)

Comment: Okay looking at the other answers I got what you mean, I adjusted it slightly and have it working perfectly now. Will update the questions with the answer.